# remover listas de um dicionário

Tags: python

tenho um código que testa varias combinações que são geradas, mas estou com um problema de erro de memória. acho que a causa disso que que o dicionário fica muito grande para ser processado, então pensei que a solução poderia ser testar a lista atual e ao mesmo tempo remover a antiga mas não sei algum comando que se encaixe com essa situação. sou novato em Python

```
#gera a lista/dicionário
for subset in genComb:
    permsList.append(subset)

#testa se o item da lista é igual a uma variavel que é definida no inicio
while desco != senha:
    desco = str(permsList[num]).replace("'", '')
    desco = desco.replace(",", '')
    desco = desco.replace(" ", '')
    desco = desco.replace("(", '')
    desco = desco.replace(")", '')
    num += 1
```

Comment: qual o erro de memória está dando?

Comment: line 20, in senhas
    permsList.append(subset)
MemoryError

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente é pelo tamanho mesmo, se você ta testando todas as combinações possiveis por exemplo de 13 caracteres diferentes ja daria 6.227.020.800 elementos na sua lista e o python tem como limite 536.870.912.

Comment: sabe de algum comando que possa apagar os elementos que ja foram usados?

Comment: para lista temos o .pop() que remove o ultimo elemento e mostra ele, o .remove() que remove o elemento que vc especificar o .clear() que remove todos.